# StrongLoop: generating application without (depreciated) slc

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

The [hello-world](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Create-a-simple-API.html) tutorial for StrongLoop/LoopBack explains how to use the application generator, `slc` for getting started. Yet the [installation guide](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installation.html) says that `slc` is no longer in active development and is depreciated.

What is its replacement intended to be? Or is the scaffolding in future intended to be written from scratch by the developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StrongLoop Arc the GUI is going to be depreciated.
slc the command line tool is going to stay.